# C# - Disposing Recursive Objects

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, idisposable

Lets say I have some object `C` that holds references to instances of itself, and also implements `IDisposable`. How should the references to other instances of `C` be disposed of? Should I recursively call their `dispose` methods or should I just set them equal to null? In other words, which of the following models is preferred?

**Model 1:** Recursive Disposing

```
public class C : IDisposable
{
    public List<C> subItems = new List<C>();

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        foreach (C subItem in subItems)
            subItem.Dispose();
        // Dispose other stuff
    }
}
```

**Model 2:** Disposing by setting equal to `null`

```
public class C : IDisposable
{
    public List<C> subItems = new List<C>();

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        subItems = null;

        // Dispose other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm, Model 2 is not disposing the sub items.

Comment: Why is your class IDisposable?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I had no reason in mind, I was just wondering for my educational benefit. This is just an abstract model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I recursively call their dispose methods

Yes.

But only when C actually needs to be `IDisposable`, which is not obvious from your code. The fact that it is referring to instances of the same class is not relevant, call Dispose() on all owned IDisposable objects.

If this is an attempt to 'help' the Garbage collector, then stop it and just do nothing.

Comment: However, be careful of loops in the object graph!

Comment: Scott, yes, the standard pattern calls for  an `isDisposed` boolean field. Most problem domains would avoid/prohibit cycles and then the posted  code is OK(-ish).

Comment: It should be noted that the GC **never** calls `.Dispose()` unless there is a finalizer that explicitly does so.

Comment: @Enigmativity - and that Finalizer (destructor) calls `Dispose(bool)`

Comment: The one you mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

> Should I recursively call their dispose methods

No. if you no need it. (GC cleaned it)

Yes. if object uses unmanaged resources. Not disposing unmanaged resources will lead to memory leaks.

Comment: _Not disposing unmanaged resources_ leads to resource leaks. It has nothing to do with memory usage.

Comment: _It has nothing to do with memory usage_ i mean in commons

Comment: _In commons_ or not, this is an often repeated myth that's simply not true. Dispose() is for cleaning up resources. It is not a alternative for GC.

Comment: You right, but GC cleaning up resources too. Or not? (=

Comment: Yes, but you should avoid needing that. The GC takes too long for resources.

Comment: @NickRimmer: Do the bumpers in your car mean there's no need to use your brakes?  GC-based resource cleanup exists mainly as a fallback to minimize the harm in case the primary cleanup mechanisms (like `Dispose`) don't do the job.  In some cases (as with bumpers), the fallback may work well enough that one can get by without using the primary mechanisms, but in general the primary mechanisms are better and one should use them whenever possible and avoid reliance on the fallback.

Comment: @NickRimmer - The GC **never** ever calls .`Dispose()` (unless there is a finalizer that explicitly calls it).

Answer (score -1):

It's not only right answer.

The main question you have to ASK - is conainer of LIST real and single OWNER of items in it?

If so - the only valid behavior - call Dispose explicitly (as in your first pseudo-code)

If items are or could be shared and can be used in another contexts rather than single container (for example as it is with StreamWriter and Stream - StreamWriter can be "owner" of Stream and close it, but you can use keepLive parameter to keep Stream opened). In shared case the only valid way would be run from such situations - because if you dispose - you could break other tasks, if not dispose and just clear list - you can keep some of resources alive without any chance to clean.

Where are ninja way for shared as it maked in shared_ptr in C++ or usual references in .NET - trace usage count -

```
class C:IDisposable{
    int usageCount = 0;
    public void AddUsage(){usageCount++;}; 
    public void Dispose(){
         if(usageCount>0){
            usageCount--;
            return;
         }
         //ELSE DO REAL DISPOSE LOGIC
    }
 }
```

BUT wish it's not your case )